# polymer google maps marker events

Tags: google-maps, polymer

Hi I need to capture the new coordinates when a marker is dragged to a new position.
I am using this type of code

```
<google-map latitude="37.779" longitude="-122.3892" minZoom="9" maxZoom="11" fit>
  <google-map-marker latitude="37.779" longitude="-122.3892" title="test" draggable="true">
  </google-map-marker>
</google-map>
```

I have tried things like adding updatePosition="{{markerUpdate}}" into the marker and using a markerUpdate function but I cannot find any event that fires when the marker is accessed. I know it is my lack of understanding but can anyone help or at least point me in the right direction.
Thanks
Sean

Comment: In standard JS you can just add an event listener as you add markers. After searching for hours I cannot find out how to do this in Polymer although I am certain there will be a way. I do data bind the lat and lon so I can get the updated coordinates from this. I have a solution but it is not so nice I will have to add a button to push and get the new values rather than using ondragend or even Map clicked events.

Answer (score 0):

Polymer uses something known as an "[Observe](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html)" block. An observe block defines a custom property/observer mapping for one or more properties as a change watcher. So, this is what fires your updatePostion() function.

```
observe: {
    latitude: 'updatePosition',
    longitude: 'updatePosition',
  },
```

From the provided information, I understand you have configured the functions onDragEnd() and I am assuming have configured a setupDragHandler_() function as well (As shown in provided sample code; If not, see the sample code below).

A good sample of making a Google Map app using Polymer can be seen [here](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-map/blob/master/google-map.html).